# LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, ruby-on-rails-4, rack-pow

We are upgrading to the latest ruby version (2.2.3) and latest rails version (4.2.4) and we can't get pass this error:

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
~/Documents/remsis/config/boot.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
~/Documents/remsis/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
~/Documents/remsis/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
~/Documents/remsis/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/builder.rb:4:in `instance_eval'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/builder.rb:4:in `initialize'
~/Documents/remsis/config.ru:1:in `new'
~/Documents/remsis/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:51:in `eval'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:51:in `load_config'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:42:in `initialize'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:12:in `new'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:12:in `run'
~/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.5.0/node_modules/nack/bin/nack_worker:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: How did you upgrade Ruby? Are you using RVM or rbenv? Did you install the bundler gem for the new Ruby version you just upgraded to?

Comment: Using RVM, changed the ruby-version to the version I want. Asked me to install the version I'm running and installed it. Going to uninstall and reinstall rvm again.

Comment: Gotcha. Make sure you install bundler after you install and change Ruby versions "gem install bundler"

Comment: @carlosramireziii Bundler version 1.10.6, I just reinstalled rvm using rvm implode. Error stays :(

Comment: The error shows you are using the system Ruby, not RVM. You need to tell Pow to use the right Ruby version.

Comment: http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_2.3.2

Comment: @matt this fixed it! Please post as answer

Comment: use RVM to run bundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error shows you are using the system Ruby, not RVM. You need to tell Pow to use the right Ruby version. You need to create a `.rvmrc` file specifying which Ruby to use, and also create or edit a `.powrc` or `.powenv` file to tell Pow to load RVM. See the [Pow docs on using RVM](http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_2.3.2).

Answer (score 4):

Create a Gemset with RVM

```
rvm use 2.2.3@yourproject --create
```

After that  install bundler gem

```
gem install bundler
```

and last step is to do bundle install

```
bundle install
```

Comment: Before running `bundle install` can you confirm that correct gemset is set i.e. `yourproject` and that you actually install bundler in your `yourproject` gemset. Also type `gem list` to see which gems are installed

Answer (score 0):

If you are using / upgrading to bundler 2 then please check this documentation:

https://bundler.io/guides/bundler_2_upgrade.html

from my experience basically, you need to be on RubyGems v2.5.0 or above otherwise you will see `cannot load such file -- bundler/setup` if you have `require 'bundler/setup'`. If you need to upgrade the rubygems you can do it by:

```
gem update --system
```

hope it helps. Thanks